# A* Graph search

Tags: artificial-intelligence, a-star

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ktdwhrT.png]

Given the heuristic values h(A)=5, h(B)=1, using A* graph search, it will put A and B on the frontier with f(A)=2+5=7, f(B)=4+1=5, then select B for expansion, then put G on frontier with f(G)=4+4=8, then it will select A for expansion, but will not do anything since both S and B are already expanded and not on frontier, and therefore it will select G next and return a non-optimal solution.

Is my argument correct?

Comment: The heuristic is admissible, but not consistent. h(A) is the estimated cost from A to G, not S to A, so it's not an overestimate. In graph search, it shouldn't reopen B since B is in the explored set, as it has already been expanded? (It should only open those nodes in the frontier/unexplored set)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You maintain an ordered priority queue of objects on the frontier. You then take the best candidate, expand in all available directions, and put the new nodes in the priority queue. So it's possible for A to be pushed to the back of queue even though in fact the optimal path goes through it. It's also possible for A to be hemmed in by neighbours which were reached through sub-optimal paths, in which case most algorithms won't try to expand it as you say.

A star is only an a way of finding a reasonable path, it doesn't find the globally optimal path.

Comment: Generally wrong. A* guarantees to find the shortest path when the heuristic function is admissible.

Answer (score 2):

There are two heuristic concepts here:

1. **Admissible heuristic**: When for each node *n* in the graph, *h(n)* **never overestimates** the cost of reaching the goal.
2. **Consistent heuristic**: When for each node *n* in the graph and each node *m* of its successors, *h(n) <= h(m) + c(n,m)*, where *c(n,m)* is the cost of the arc from *n* to *m*.

Your heuristic function is admissible but not consistent, since as you have shown:

*h(A) > h(B) + c(A,B), 5 > 2*.

If the heuristic is consistent, then the estimated final cost of a partial solution will always grow along the path, i.e. *f(n) <= f(m)* and as we can see again:

*f(A) = g(A) + h(A) = 7 > f(B) = g(B) + h(B) = 5*,

this heuristic function does not satisfy this property.

With respect to A*:

1. A* using an admissible heuristic **guarantees to find the shortest path from the start to the goal**.
2. A* using a consistent heuristic, in addition to find the shortest path, **also guarantees that once a node is explored we have already found the shortest path to this node, and therefore no node needs to be reexplored**.

So, answering your question, A* algorithm has to be implemented to reopen nodes when a shorter path to a node is found (updating also the new path cost), and this new path will be added to the open set or frontier, therefore your argument is not correct, **since B has to be added again to the frontier (now with the path S->A->B and cost 3)**.

If you can restrict A* to be used only with consistent heuristic functions then yes, you can discard path to nodes that have been already explored.